# Can I tunnel to a host-only device?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, virtualbox

I have a tricky routing/tunnelling question, hoping someone can help.

My setup is this: On my lan, I have a Ubuntu workstation and a Windows 7 PC.

The Windows 7 PC is running Oracle Virtual Box, and has a virtual Centos image.  This image has 2 network interfaces: Host only and Nat.

The image is a web development environment which is running a web server on port 4444.  I can connect to this from the host PC easily enough via the host-only interface.

I'd like to connect to it from the Ubuntu workstation as well.

Is there any way I can do this without reconfiguring the networking on the VM?  Can I use ssh from the windows pc to the ubuntu workstation to open a tunnel backwards and allow it to access the host-only network?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't give the VM a bridged interface?

Comment: I'd rather not mess with the VM settings if possible.